# -Django- Got "Cannot assign "u'Wing'": "Truck.MODEL" must be a "MODEL" instance" when creating new object to database

Tags: python, html, django

models.py:

```
class MODEL(models.Model):
    ModelName = models.CharField(max_length = 128, unique = True)
    URL_Slug = models.SlugField(unique = True)
    ...

class Maker(models.Model):
    maker = models.CharField(max_length = 128, unique = True)
    URL_Slug = models.SlugField(unique = True)
    ...
class Truck(models.Model):
    MODEL = models.ForeignKey(MODEL)
    CarID = models.CharField(max_length = 10, unique = True, null = False)
    Maker = models.ForeignKey(Maker)   
    year = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.CarID
```

forms.py:

```
class MODELForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ModelName = forms.CharField(max_length = 128, help_text = 'Enter the NEW model name')
    URL_Slug = forms.SlugField(widget = forms.HiddenInput(), required = False)

    class Meta:
        model = MODEL
        fields = ('ModelName', )

class MakerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    maker = forms.CharField(max_length = 128, help_text = 'Enter the NEW maker')
    URL_Slug = forms.SlugField(widget = forms.HiddenInput(), required = False)

    class Meta:
        model = Maker
        fields = ('maker', )

class TruckForm(forms.ModelForm):
    MODEL = forms.CharField(max_length = 128, help_text = 'Enter the NEW model name')
    CarID = forms.CharField(max_length = 10, help_text = 'Enter the NEW truck ID')
    Maker = forms.CharField(max_length = 128, help_text = 'Enter the NEW maker')   
    year = forms.IntegerField(help_text = 'Enter the year of production')

    class Meta:
        model = Truck
        fields = ('MODEL', 'CarID', 'Maker', 'year')
```

views.py:

```
def add_Truck(request):
    form = TruckForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TruckForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit = True)
            return index(request)

        else:
            print(form.errors)
    return render(request, 'APP/addTruck.html', {'form': form})
```

HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form id = "Truck" method = "post" action = "/APP/NewTruck/">
                {%csrf_token%}
                {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                    {{field.errors}}
                    {{field.help_text}}
                    {{field}}<br/>
                {% endfor %}
                <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Create Truck">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to create a new object in the addTruck.html, I guest that because of MODEL and Maker are foreign keys, when creating Truck object, MODEL and Maker field should also be object.

Traceback:

Here is the Traceback from terminal Macbook:

-

> [07/Aug/2017 09:14:04] "GET /APP/NewTruck/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1240
>   Internal Server Error: /APP/NewTruck/ Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 39, in inner
>          response = get_response(request)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 187, in _get_response
>          response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 185, in _get_response
>          response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "/Users/apple/WebWorkshop/TKTrading/APP/views.py", line 88, in
>   add_Truck
>          if form.is_valid():   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py",
>   line 169, in is_valid
>          return self.is_bound and not self.errors   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py",
>   line 161, in errors
>          self.full_clean()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py",
>   line 372, in full_clean
>          self._post_clean()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py",
>   line 388, in _post_clean
>          self.instance = construct_instance(self, self.instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py",
>   line 60, in construct_instance
>          f.save_form_data(instance, cleaned_data[f.name])   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py",
>   line 833, in save_form_data
>          setattr(instance, self.name, data)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py",
>   line 211, in **set**
>          self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name, ValueError: Cannot assign "u'Wing'": "Truck.MODEL" must be a "MODEL" instance.
>   [07/Aug/2017 09:14:42] "POST /APP/NewTruck/ HTTP/1.1" 500 93290

Comment: add full traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `TruckForm`,

```
MODEL = forms.CharField(max_length = 128, help_text = 'Enter the NEW model name')
```

in your models,

```
MODEL = models.ForeignKey(MODEL)
```

**ForeignKey fields need to be instances of the corresponding models, rather than plain text**. Error message is very specific about that. In your case, if you want to create new model for a new truck everytime, you may need to override the `save()` method of your `ModelForm` for appropriate reasons. Or else if you want to choose a model from existing `MODELs`, either you could let Django use the default select widget for the field or you can override that too by defining a custom widget.

```
MODEL = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MODEL.objects.all())
#something like this.
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The problem has been solve. Cheers mate!

Comment: Welcome.. Appreciate the support mate!!